# How to change value of DefaultValue attribute in subclass

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible, but I figured I'd ask.

I have an abstract base class that has a property that's decorated with a `DefaultValue` attribute, like so:

```
public abstract MyBaseClass {

    [DefaultValue( "some value" )]
    public string StringProperty { 
        get { return iStringProperty; }
        set { iStringProperty = value;
    }
    protected string iStringProperty = "some value";

    // Other code here
}
```

I want to derive a child class from `MyBaseClass`, but I want the value in the `DefaultValue` attribute, as well as the default value of the property, to be different.  To that end, I have added a default constructor to the child class, as follows:

```
public class MyChildClass : MyBaseClass {

    // Type specific properties & fields here

    public MyChildClass()
        : base() {
        iStringProperty = "new value";
    }

    // Other code here
}
```

How do I change the value of the `DefaultValue` attribute in the derived class so it's "new value"?

Comment: You can't change the value of an attribute at run-time, so what you're trying is not possible.

Comment: It doesn't have to be done at run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your property is virtual you could override it and apply `DefaultValue` for it.

```
[DefaultValue( "new value" )]
public override string StringProperty
{ 
    get { return iStringProperty; }
    set { iStringProperty = value;}
}
```

If not, you need to shadow the property with `new` keyword and apply your new `DefaultValue`

```
[DefaultValue( "new value" )]
public new string StringProperty 
{ 
    get { return iStringProperty; }
    set { iStringProperty = value;}
}
```

In both the cases you don't need to provide new implementation. You could delegate the call to `base.StringProperty`;